# How to identify iOS device across multiple apps?

Tags: ios, objective-c

As you have understood from the question's title, I would like to know, how to identify iOS device across multiple apps. Advertising identifier and identifier for vendor is not an option for me, as apps may not have `AdSupport` framework included, and they may not have similar vendors. MAC address of the device is also deprecated. Any working solution on this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a way to retrieve the device's serial number I think using `IOKit` but if you utilise this then your App will be rejected by App review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality is explicitly disallowed by Apple. Any workaround you come up with will violate Apple's stated goal of preventing it (so you would obviously risk appstore rejection even if it "works"). You are not allowed to track devices. You are only allowed to track the vendor ID and advertising ID. Apple has steadily removed every other tool because those are the ones they intend you to use (and their limitations are intentional).

What you *are* allowed to do is track users by issuing them login credentials and having them log into your server. This usually works fine if the user actually wants the functionality you're providing by tracking them (for example, users don't mind logging into Facebook or Twitter). If you are tracking users or devices to achieve a goal the users don't actually want (such as targeted advertising that the user can't control, or attempts at digital rights management tied to devices), you're unlikely to find a supported or permitted solution.